# Is there any way to get the social events to happen more often?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

I'm pretty close to the end of the game and am trying to complete challenges.

All three of the social challenges are still open, and all three at 2 apiece. On a different person's account, I saw all three completed before they got into the third sequence but I can't seem to find Royal Convoys, White Whales, or Community/Social Chests to save my life.

It's gotten to the point where I'm wondering if it has something to do with my friends who also play ACIV or something because I can't seem to get anywhere with it.

Comment: What platform are you playing? Social events are either hit or miss depending on what platform you're on. On PC for instance, there have not been any community events and social events seem to work at random for random people. Personally, I haven't seen any yet. I'm already 100% on the progress, just can't finish challenges that depend on the broken system. Usually the answer to this is to wait for UBI to fix the problem when they fix it (if they fix it).

Comment: @JeffMercado I'm playing on the PS3 and I was only asking because a friend of my brother's got it so fast I thought it might be somehow related to the number of friends who also play ACIV.

Comment: I'm also playing on the PC, so I'll just share my observations. I found the Royal Convoys very quickly. The Chests and White Whales not so fast though. I still need to share 2 more White Whales... I didn't find my first whale until I hit 99% completion.

Comment: More anecdotal data: I play on 360 and had no friends (that I'm aware of) playing. I found that I stumbled across chests, whales and convoys pretty regularly (I'd guess at least 20 chests by completion time). Whales and convoys are harder to estimate because I never bothered detouring for them but I would be pretty sure I got them all well before game completion. Obviously the latter ones you find sailing around so if you fast travel everywhere you will reduce chances of finding but I'd have guessed that wouldn't have been a factor for me.

Comment: I've played everything on the PS4 (online) and have yet to find any of the 3 events. :(

Comment: There is apparently a petition being signed. http://www.change.org/en-GB/petitions/ubisoft-fix-the-social-events-system-within-assassin-s-creed-4-black-flag

Answer (score 1):

You can locate convoys by talking to bartenders and paying for info.  I either get a location for a convoy or for a cadaver which then has a cool item on him like a treasure map. Some bars have given me info more than once when I come back at a later time. If the bartender "glows" when you look at him, he has info!
I read that the white whale shows up randomly when you are playing while on line.  I check my fleet and stay connected.  Check your map frequently and look for a whale icon that is glowing light blue, then get there quick!  When it happened for me, there was a clock running, so if I didn't get there on time, he would have been gone.

Answer (score 0):

I found that playing the game trying for 100% completion worked for me. I played the story missions as normal, but got all side quests and viewpoints done as well and repeated as necessary. The collectibles on the smaller islands worked for the white whale and the Ambegris Key (Spelling?) if you repeatedly fast traveled there and turned around a convoy spawned. Hope this helps.